# Sending http headers in form submission CasperJS

Tags: javascript, http-headers, phantomjs, form-submit, casperjs

I have a test step with CasperJS that does the following:

```
this.fillSelectors("#registration-form", {
    "#first-name": "Bob",
    "#last-name": "Smith",
    "#email-address": RANDOM_EMAIL,
    "#password": PASSWORD,
    "#password-confirm": PASSWORD
}, true);
```

I want to be able to send a HTTP header along with this. I can't seem to find a way of doing this without "manually" posting the form, which isn't the kind of test I want here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easier way than the one below. You can access the [`casper.page.customHeaders`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html) property of PhantomJS' Webpage instance.

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.page.customHeaders = {
        "CuStOm": "Header"
    }; // set headers
    this.fillSelectors("#registration-form", { /*...*/ }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    casper.page.customHeaders = {}; // reset headers
});
```

The problem is that this method will add your custom header to every request until you disable it again. You can experiment with resetting headers based on `setTimeout` or directly behind `fillSelectors`.

---

You [cannot set headers for a form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047711/custom-http-request-headers-in-html) in the browser. [`__utils__.sendAJAX`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#sendajax) also doesn't provide custom headers.

You will need to use XMLHttpRequest to send the request. The following function replaces the submit handler of the form to send the Ajax call and also waits:

```
casper.thenFormToXHR = function(formSelector, data, customHeaders){
    this.thenEvaluate(function(formSelector, customHeaders){
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838177/1816580
        function submitForm(oFormElement) {
            window.__requestDone = false;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(var header in customHeaders) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, customHeaders[header]);
            }
            xhr.onload = function(){
                window.__requestDone = true;
            };
            xhr.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
            xhr.send (new FormData(oFormElement));
            return false;
        }
        document.querySelector(formSelector).onsubmit = submitForm;
    }, formSelector, customHeaders);
    this.then(function(){
        this.fillSelectors(formSelector, data, true);
    });
    this.waitFor(function check(){
        return this.evaluate(function(){
            return window.__requestDone;
        });
    });
};
```

You can then invoke like this:

```
casper.thenFormToXHR("#registration-form", {
    "#first-name": "Bob",
    "#last-name": "Smith",
    "#email-address": RANDOM_EMAIL,
    "#password": PASSWORD,
    "#password-confirm": PASSWORD
}, {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" // here should be your custom headers
});
```

The code can be reduced, if you don't need to wait for the XHR completion:

```
casper.formToXHR = function(formSelector, data, customHeaders){
    this.evaluate(function(formSelector, customHeaders){
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19838177/1816580
        function submitForm(oFormElement) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(var header in customHeaders) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, customHeaders[header]);
            }
            xhr.open (oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
            xhr.send (new FormData(oFormElement));
            return false;
        }
        document.querySelector(formSelector).onsubmit = submitForm;
    }, formSelector, customHeaders);
    this.fillSelectors(formSelector, data, true);
};
```

Comment: That's good, but could we handle http request out of the browser by using something like `superagent`?

Comment: @Sayakiss Since superagent is a browser library, no, you cannot use it out of the browser. However, there is a node.js server counterpart, but I don't know if it can be used to do requests. Either way, PhantomJS is not node.js. Most node.js modules cannot be used in PhantomJS/CasperJS.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Why not make a pull request to make `__utils__.sendAJAX` support custom headers? I post a issue about that: [Issue #1560](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1560).

Comment: @ArtjomB. I came out with another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048190/how-to-synchronous-call-child-process-in-casperjs), could you please give me some advices