# Add custom header on non-ajax post

Tags: html, forms, post, header, html-post

AFAIK it's not possible to set a header field when a form is submited, it can only be done in ajax requests

This questions also points that it's not possible:

- [How to set a Header field on POST a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516865/how-to-set-a-header-field-on-post-a-form)
- [Custom HTTP Request headers in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047711/custom-http-request-headers-in-html)

But reading [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) it's mentioned that:

> **Encrypted Token Pattern**
>
> **Overview**
>
> The Encrypted Token Pattern leverages an encryption, rather than
>   comparison, method of Token-validation. After successful
>   authentication, the server generates a unique Token comprised of the
>   user's ID, a timestamp value and a nonce, using a unique key available
>   only on the server. This Token is returned to the client and embedded
>   in a hidden field. Subsequent AJAX requests include this Token in the
>   request-header, in a similar manner to the Double-Submit pattern.
>   **Non-AJAX form-based requests will implicitly persist the Token in its hidden field, although I recommend persisting this data in a
>   custom HTTP header in such cases**. On receipt of this request, the
>   server reads and decrypts the Token value with the same key used to
>   create the Token.

This sentence confuses me:

> I recommend persisting this data in a custom HTTP header in such cases

Could anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence implies that the POST operation is invoked by a custom JavaScript handler in order to inject the AUTH header. I've corrected the OWASP description to reflect this oversight.

Comment: Does this mean that posting using a built-in form post is kind of obsolete because it cannot be guarded against CSRF ? Setting a hidden field inside each and every form is also error-prone (as is replacing post with ajax)