# Can we add http response headers directly into html pages

Tags: html, jsp, http, response-headers

I need to add response headers like X-Frame, Cache-control, Pragma etc directly into the html code, may be, using attributes in html elements?

It is for help pages which are directly coming from a directory via href link.

Is there any way to add headers to these htmls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom HTTP Request headers in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047711/custom-http-request-headers-in-html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `meta` to replicate some of these. Normally not the ideal solution, but look into the `http-equiv` attribute of `meta` tags. I believe a lot of these have been deprecated in newer browsers.

**Examples:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"/>

<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="sameorigin"/>

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

Comment: OWASP disagrees with this answer:
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.html#common-defense-mistakes

Comment: Sadly you can't do this for all of the HTTP headers, only a few, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#http-equiv

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-Robots-Tag" content="index, follow" />`
Will this work as well? I doubt not.

Answer (score 8):

In short: no, you cannot. HTML files are the **body** of an HTTP response; the headers must come from the server. Anything you could embed in the HTML file would just become part of the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this, if php execution is enabled on your web server:

```
<?php
http_response_code(your_response_code)
?>
rest-of-your-html-code
```

This will execute a php script that will set the response code.

Comment: The OP wants to add "headers", not response code using HTML